QML: How to select a row in GridLayout
I want when I click or hover over a row in a GridLayout to change its background.
How can I do this?
I tried to create a custom row for this action, but got stuck on the fact that I would have to create several such objects for each field (ComboBox, Label, TextInput, Button).
Here is my code for the resulting row:
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 200
    height: 20
    color: field.activeFocus ? "#a6a6a6" : (hovered ? "#c0c0c0" : "#eaeaea")
    property bool hovered: false

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked: {
            field.forceActiveFocus()
        }
        onEntered: { hovered = true}
        onExited: { hovered = false}
    }

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        Label
        {
            id: label
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 0
            text: "Unknown"
            Layout.minimumWidth: 80
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.weight: field.activeFocus ? Font.Bold : Font.Normal

        }
        Label // ComboBox // TextInput // Button
        {
            id: field
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 1
            text: "Unknown"
            Layout.minimumWidth: 80
            Layout.minimumHeight: 20
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}

Here is where it will be used:


I would replace the GridLayout with a ColumnLayout, and have each element inside it be a Rectangle that contains a RowLayout. Then when the mouse hovers, you can change the color of the Rectangle.

Here's one potential solution to your problem.

Create a dummy parent Item and allow it to receive focus with focus: true
Also allow the dummy parent to receive to receive custom children with default property alias children: ctl.children

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    Column {
        spacing: 10
        Special { Label { text: "Empty" } }
        Special { Label { text: "0" } }
        Special { Label { text: "0" } }
        Special { Label { text: "0" } }
        Special { ComboBox { model: ["Empty"] } }
        Special { Button { text: "Button" } }
    }
}

// Special.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Item {
    id: control
    width: 400
    height: 40
    focus: true
    default property alias children: ctl.children
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: control.activeFocus ? "#a6a6a6" : (mouseArea.hovered ? "#c0c0c0" : "#eaeaea")
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: control.forceActiveFocus()
        property bool hovered: false
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: { hovered = true }
        onExited: { hovered = false }
    }
    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        Label
        {
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 0
            text: "Label:"
            Layout.minimumWidth: 80
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.weight: control.activeFocus ? Font.Bold : Font.Normal
        }
        Item // ComboBox // TextInput // Button
        {
            id: ctl
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.minimumWidth: 80
            Layout.minimumHeight: 20
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}

You can Try it Online!
